# Relationship between graph edge count and coverability

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected graph on $n$ nodes, $m$ edges.  A graph is $(b, r)$ coverable if it can be covered by $b$ balls of radius $r$ (in other words, there is a set of $b$ nodes such that all nodes are within distance $r$ of one of these $b$ nodes).  Suppose $G$ is $(b, r)$ coverable.

Intuitively, I feel like there should be a nice relationship between $m, b,$ and $r$.  For example, if $m$ is set to its minimum value ($n-1$), then we have the relationship $b(2r+1) \ge n$ (because the nodes are arranged in one big chain).  Alternately, if $m$ is set to its maximum value ($n(n-1)$), then $G$ is the complete graph and it is trivially $(1, 1)$ coverable.

Is there some bound of the form $f(b, r, m) \ge g(n, m)$ that generalizes these examples?

Answer (score 1):

If your graph is $k$-regular, then you can approximate diameter with $log_{k}(n)$. Let $\delta(G) := min \{ d(v) : v \in V(G) \}$. You can bound the diameter above by $\lceil log_{\delta(G)}(n) \rceil$. Similarly, let $\Delta(G)$ be the maximal degree of the graph, and you can use it to get a lower bound on the diameter. Make sure to floor the lower bound.

Comment: This diameter approximation is only true of random graphs, yes?  I think I can imagine a $k$-regular graph of diameter $O(n)$ (looks approximately like a chain of $k$-cliques).

Comment: It approximates random walks, yes. It's useful elsewhere, too. It holds true for the Petersen Graph, as an example. It's true for trees as well. Are you familiar with the height of a binary tree being no bigger than $\lceil log_{2}(n) \rceil$? Also, you'll probably want to floor the lower bound and ceil the upper bound, so as to make sure you're dealing with integers. If you string together a bunch of triangles, as described, you get $log_{3}(7)$ as your approximation, which when ceiled gives you $3$, which is the length.

Comment: To clarify, the logarithmic approximation would be for a balanced binary tree.